# Why does checking then setting verticalNormalizedPosition restrict ScrollRect scrolling?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, scrollrect

Unity NGUI system uses ScrollRects to add scrollable elements to your game, but this scrollrect lacks the ability to restrict scrolling up past a certain point, something I determined to implement.

I had an idea: lets just check if `ScrollRect.verticalNormalizedPosition` is 1, and if it is, set it to 1 (1 being the top part of the ScrollRect.)

```
public class scrollrectclamper: MonoBehaviour {
    ScrollRect SR;
    void Start () {
        SR= gameObject.GetComponent<ScrollRect> ();
    }
    void Update(){
        if (SR.verticalNormalizedPosition == 1) {
            SR.verticalNormalizedPosition = 1; // WHY
        }
    }
}
```

This restricts scrolling even though I wouldn't even expect `== 1` to work with a `float`, a type infamous for its imprecision.

The description of `verticalNormalizedPosition` says:

> The vertical scroll position as a value between 0 and 1, with 0 being at the bottom.

But the function is broken only ever returns floats 1.0 if the scrollrect is at the top or above, and 0.0 if it's anywhere else.

Comment: `==1` is probably causing an implicit cast to an integer.

Comment: How about posting a few lines of codes that we can use to reproduce your problem, instead of posting a long story?

Comment: Help us help you. Consider showing us the code snippet(s) you had and the result(s) you got, in clearly separated sections, instead of describing it in natural language.

Comment: Is it possible that `verticalNormalizedPosition` is a property with something like `get { return Mathf.Clamp(verticalUnclampedPosition, 0, 1); }`, and with a `set { verticalUnclampedPosition = value; }`? That could explain the behaviour. I feel I may have misunderstood, sorry if this sounds silly. '~'

Comment: What looks like a useless assignment may well trigger a setter with all sorts of side-effects or syn'ching.

Comment: @Zan I've edited your post to make it shorter and add a descriptive title. Please look it over and edit it again if I missed something, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Because the `set` clause of `veritcalNormalizedPosition` fires a method which actively changes the position of the scroll rect. As long as you dont mess with the value it will be clamped between `0` and `1` and `get`'ting the variable wont trigger any behaviors. But as soon as you `set` the variable, you are telling the `NGUI` engine, "i want this to be here." thus, a method is fired.